# embedded jetty does not report startup failure

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using an embedded Jetty.
I'm trying to use the Jetty's Server lifeCycleEvents to know when the Jetty failed to start. Specifically, I try to load it using a port that is not free.
What I see is that the `lifeCycleStarted()` method is called, when I expect the `lifeCycleFailure()` to be called.

How should I  figure out that the Jetty couldn't start?
See code below:

```
_server = new Server(port);
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
DefaultHandler defaultHandler = new DefaultHandler();
_server.setHandler(handlers);
_server.addLifeCycleListener(new LifeCycle.Listener()
{
  public void lifeCycleStarting(org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle lifeCycle) {}
  public void lifeCycleStopping(org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle lifeCycle) {}
  public void lifeCycleStopped(org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle lifeCycle)  {}
  public void lifeCycleStarted(org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle lifeCycle)
  {
    loadCompleted(port, true);
  }
  public void lifeCycleFailure(org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle lifeCycle, java.lang.Throwable throwable) 
  {
    loadCompleted(port, false);
  }

   private void loadCompleted(int port, boolean success)
   {
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Server.start` throws `java.net.BindException` if port is already in use. You could simply catch it.

Comment: Missed that. Caught the exception and did nothing with it. Thank you